# Objective-C 'Robot' may not respond to '-nothingToDo'

Tags: objective-c

Guys, I have two classes AppController and Robot.

```
AppController.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "Robot.h"

@interface AppController : NSObject {

 Robot *myRobot;

}
- (IBAction)initPort:(id)sender;


AppController.m

#import "AppController.h"
@implementation AppController


- (IBAction)initPort:(id)sender
{
 [myRobot nothingDo];
}
@end

Robot.h

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface Robot : NSObject {

}
-(void)nothingToDo:(id)sender;


Robot.m
#import "Robot.h"

@implementation Robot

-(void)nothingToDo:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"bla-bla-bla");
}
```

When I'm trying to run I see 'Robot' may not respond to '-nothingToDo' and -(void)nothingToDo is not being performed. What 's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The colons in an Objective-C method is significant. Try

```
[myRobot nothingToDo:sender];
```

instead.

Comment: Yeah, it helps:)))) But, I didn't know about colon before. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're sending the message `nothingDo`, and not `nothingToDo` (might be just a typo).

Furthermore, you forgot the `sender` parameter.

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)initPort:(id)sender
{
   [myRobot nothingToDo:sender];
}
```

This should work, provided `myRobot` is a properly allocated and initialized`Robot` object.

Comment: Yeah, it helps:)))) But, I didn't know about colon before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Start by making sure `myRobot` references a valid `Robot` object.

Answer (score -1):

When compiling `AppController.m` the compiler is not aware of private `-nothingToDo` method since it does not appear in `Robot.h`. This is why a warning is issued.

Actually, this method doesn't exist, only `-nothingToDo:` (note the `:` meaning an argument is needed). This is why the method is not called.

Comment: You were downvoted because the method is declared in the header correctly and the real problem is that the question is sending the method `nothingDo` instead of `nothignToDo:`, a case of mistyping method name AND missing the sender parameter. The warning is true, robot doesn't respond to those messages.

Comment: Let's leave the typo out of discussion, it's easy to fix. Anyway, `-nothingToDo` does not appear in the header file, only `-nothingToDo:`

Comment: Yeah, it helps:)))) But, I didn't know about colon before. Thanks